# mysql query for select last updated data for one day from more than two updates

Tags: mysql

Ex:

Table data as shownbelow. I need the query for the result as shown in the below. Help me guys...
Data

```
Data            
date    time    temperature updated_time
01-04-2015  0:00    30  1:00:00 AM
01-04-2015  1:00    31  
01-04-2015  2:00    32  
01-04-2015  3:00    30  
01-04-2015  4:00    31  
.   .   .   .
.   .   .   .
.   .   .   .
01-04-2015  24:00:00    30  1:00:00 AM

01-04-2015  3:00    30  3:00:00 AM
01-04-2015  4:00    31  3:00:00 AM
01-04-2015  5:00    32  3:00:00 AM
01-04-2015  6:00    30  3:00:00 AM
.   .   .   .
.   .   .   .
.   .   .   .
01-04-2015  24:00:00    30  3:00:00 AM

01-04-2015  6:00    30  6:00:00 AM
01-04-2015  7:00    31  6:00:00 AM
01-04-2015  8:00    32  6:00:00 AM
01-04-2015  9:00    30  6:00:00 AM
.   .   .   .
.   .   .   .
.   .   .   .
01-04-2015  24:00:00    30  6:00:00 AM
```

Result Will be

```
date    time    temperature updated_time
01-04-2015  0:00    30  1:00:00 AM
01-04-2015  1:00    31  1:00:00 AM
01-04-2015  2:00    32  1:00:00 AM
01-04-2015  3:00    30  3:00:00 AM
01-04-2015  4:00    30  3:00:00 AM
01-04-2015  5:00    31  3:00:00 AM
01-04-2015  6:00    32  6:00:00 AM
01-04-2015  7:00    30  6:00:00 AM

.   .   .   .
.   .   .   .
.   .   .   .

01-04-2015  21:00   30  9:00:00 PM
01-04-2015  22:00   30  9:00:00 PM
01-04-2015  23:00   30  9:00:00 PM
```

Comment: Step 1 is to store dates/times using the correct data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data table looks something like

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    date date,
    time time,
    temperature decimal, 
    updated_time time
);
```

the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT date, time, temperature, updated_time 
FROM data d1
WHERE d1.updated_time=
    (SELECT MAX(updated_time) FROM data d2 WHERE d2.date=d1.date and d2.time=d1.time)
ORDER BY date, time;
```